# How to manipulate DOM after a template is rendered by jsRender?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsrender

I know we can wire events onto the newly added DOM elements using `$(document).on(event, selector, function)`. But how can I do some jQuery on those elements.

Say, I need to add `datepicker` onto some `input[type=date]`. How can I do it?

----Update-----

My external template is supposed to be placed into

```
<div id="form-output">
</div>
```

But even when the form is displayed in the browser, the DOM from the template is not inside the div above. How can I access those DOMs using jQuery?

Comment: From your update, are you saying that you add the rendered template to the div, it displays in the browser, but does not exist in the div? And when you say "external template", is it something you are loading via ajax before rendering, and if so are you doing all your manipulation of the returned content in the ajax callback (adding to the div, attaching datepicker, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

jsRender does everything a-sync. It also doesn't have any kind of callback functions so create your own with:

```
$.when( { dojsRenderStuff } ).done(
       function(){ $("input[type=date]").datepicker();
    } 
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Thanks. but then dom element is not in the page. please see my update.

Comment: jsRender's `.render()` function is synchronous and returns the result of the render (that's why there are no callback functions). If that result were added to the DOM (using `.append()`, for example), it could immediately be selected.